# C++ Redistributable Not Allowed On Server

Tags: c#, c++, .net, security, dll

I'm wrapping up development of a project for a client, and it has a dependency (via ImageMagick) on the [Visual C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Are there any well-known (vulnerability) reasons why you wouldn't want this installed on a server? They're suggesting I copy all of my dependencies, along with the redistributable dependencies, into my bin directory. This seems very superfluous to me, but how would I begin accomplishing that task?

Is there a solution that gives a middle-ground?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the redistributable packaged is **not** digitally signed don't place it on a server.

Comment: They seem to be subscribing to an old (outdated?) audit idea that production servers must not have any development tools installed. At the same time the redistributable is not, strictly speaking, a development tool. Signing is irrelevant here by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They're suggesting I copy all of my dependencies, along with the redistributable dependencies, into my bin directory

This can become a slippery slope (side-by-side installations). The problem arises when the version you are distributing is updated due to a vulnerability. As far as I know, your [now outdated] version will not be updated.

Stefan Kanthak was having a lot of fun with sort of thing on Full Disclosure for a while. See, for example, [How well does Microsoft support (and follow) their mantra "keep your PC updated"?](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Aug/113).

---

> Is there a solution that gives a middle-ground?

When I build my installers (with [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)), I carry around the latest version of the runtime. I always install it, whether its needed or not. If its not needed, the installer exits immediately. The Microsoft installer puts the runtime in a place where its updated by the system, so I don't have to fuss with it.

The nice thing about [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is you can have multiple platforms in the setup program. That is, you have one installer with both x86 and x64. Wix does not allow you to do that (or it did not in the past, which is why I used Inno).  So your setup program will always have the correct version of what you need.

Another benefit to including the runtime with your setup is you avoid the need to tell a user to visit a site and install a prerequisite. It also avoids the need to have the user visit your server to download the runtime.

If you've never worked with Inno, its very easy. You'll have a setup program that does everything you need in a couple of hours. Its scripting based, and its about as hard as working with a Windows INI file. See, for example, [Script Format Overview](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptformatoverview).

---

Also see [Deployment (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in MSDN.